# HTML5 and CSS3 dropdown menu display errors

Tags: html, css

Good morning,

I have implemented a drop down menu using html and css only, however I have run into two issues.

The first is that the data behind the menu is still displayed and can be seen "though" the menu, I tried a few things such as z-index to no avail and wasn't sure if I'd missed anything?

The second issue is that clicking the links in the menu bar don't work, however they do work when the screen is expanded and displayed normally.

I have created a plunk to illustrate the issue:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>EXAMPLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menuButton.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav id="mainNavigation">
    <img src="example.png" alt="Logo">
    <div>
        <button id="expandMenuButton">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </button>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="TEST">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="pageContent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.css

```
body {
    background: #666;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.pageContent {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#mainNavigation {
    background: #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
}
#mainNavigation > img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 80px;
}
#mainNavigation > div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin-left: auto;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#mainNavigation > div > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    visibility: visible;
}
#mainNavigation > div > ul > li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#mainNavigation > div > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
    #mainNavigation > div {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    #mainNavigation > div > ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch;
    }
    #mainNavigation > div > button {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #mainNavigation > div {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    #mainNavigation > div > ul {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #mainNavigation > div > button:focus ~ ul {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #mainNavigation > div > ul > li {
        background: #888;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 30px 15px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}
```

menuBar.css

```
#expandMenuButton {
  background: inherit;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  min-height: 60px;
}

#expandMenuButton:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#expandMenuButton > .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: 1s;
}

/* Rotate bars on click */

#expandMenuButton:focus > .bar1 {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#expandMenuButton:focus > .bar2 {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#expandMenuButton:focus > .bar3 {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/yiFvqED51uhqpFTaQsc8?p=info

To summarise my main questions are how to hide all elements behind one element, and how to enable links to be clicked when an element is only showed using a siblings :focus css.

Let me know if you need any more info!

Just a note, some people weren't sure what to do with the plunkr:

Reduce the size of the window until the menu is hidden, then click on the three lines to open the menu this should display like this:

[image: Plunkr Example]

Comment: I don't understand. Is your plnkr working?

Comment: You have a button with three div's, but there's nothing in there. Is that what you want?

Comment: clicking on the button should open a drop down menu, might be an issue as I haven't made it cross compatible with multiple browsers my bad!

Comment: I've updated the main question now with more information and a picture of the display issues, still no idea why clicking the links doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I'm sorry I must have been being silly!

To hide the information behind the dropdown I just needed to add z-index: 1; to the UL (I think I was adding it to the li before).

To enable the buttons to be clicked I needed to add:

```
#mainNavigation > div > ul:hover {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

This meant that while the ul was hovered over it was still being included in the dom and therefore displayed :)

Answer (score -1):

just remove

`#mainNavigation > div {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }`

from app.css line no 61

Comment: What was this supposed to fix? It just moved the menu up for me, there was still the issue with divs behind showing through, clicking the links wasn't fixed either?